# iOS non-arc: should I use autorelease when self.property = [[Obj alloc] init]?

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I have the below property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObject *theObject;
```

then if I want to create a new MyObject, do I:

```
self.theObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
```

or:

```
self.theObject = [[[MyObject alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you can't use ARC?

Comment: @Fogmeister Perhaps he wants to know what he is doing...

Comment: Perhaps, but I'd pretty much always stick to using ARC if possible. Was just checking if it was a necessity.

Comment: @Fogmeister or backwards-compatibility. Or whatever. If someone wants to use MRC, at least don't discourage it.

Comment: At which point did I discourage it? I only asked if there was a particular reason to use it. Jeez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use autorelease. If you don't, the object will have a release count of two (one from `alloc`, one from the `retain` by the setter), so when the property is unset, it'll be leaked.

This only applies to strong or retained and copy properties. Assigned and weak properties should just be assigned an alloc-initted object, since they don't alter its reference count.

Comment: ***ANY reason for the unjust, no-brainer downvote???*** This answer isn't technically incorrect.

Comment: If you alloc, init and assign to a non-retaining pointer (not just properties, could be local, static or global variables) you must either use autorelease or release the object manually before you overwrite the pointer.

Comment: @Minthos **But not when assigning!** And that was the question. An accessor that doesn't touch the refcount doesn't alter other memory management rules...

Answer (score 2):

If you must - the second.

If you are using the generated setter, you have marked it with `retain`. Which means that the value stored in that property will be retained for you, so you don't need to pass it an owned object.

Since it is retained, you need to release it in your dealloc.